# If the half life of the Uranium $230$ isotope is $20.8$ days, how much of a given amount of the isotope will be left after $104$ days?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If the half life of the Uranium $230$ isotope is $20.8$ days, how much of a given amount of the isotope will be left after $104$ days?

I'm getting $1/32$. The answer key says $1/16$.

$104/20.8 = 5$

The first term plus 5 half lives means there are 6 total terms.

$a = (1/2)^5 (n)$

$a = (1/32)n$

Comment: You are right and "they" are wrong. Who is "they"? Whose "answer key" is it?

Comment: Modern Algebra and trigonometry Structure and Method by Mary Dolciani 1965 edition

Comment: Oh... I don't think they accept errata submissions anymore.

Comment: I wonder how we come to be speaking of a "first term" here. It makes me suspect that the book presented the material in a more complicated way than necessary. Perhaps it is so unnecessarily complicated that even the author got confused by it, hence the wrong answer in the answer key. It might be wise to see if another book on the topic is available, at least to see how someone else treats the same topic.

Answer (score 1):

community wiki answer so the post can be closed

Your solution is correct.  The answer key is wrong.